# In the big bang model did the universe reach its current size in less than one day?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

I read that the [Inflationary Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflationary_epoch) is posited to have lasted $10^{-32}s$. That seems quite quick.

In the big bang model did the universe therefore essentially reach the size it is now in less than one day?

I am look to see some numbers and calculations of the rate of expansion one day after the big bang and also now.

This question was also provoked by reading the flatness problem, so any an answer that helps understand that as well is one I seek.

Comment: Can you explain your “therefore”? I don’t understand your reasoning.

Comment: That would hardly seem possible, given that the universe is expanding, and thus its current size is continually increasing.  A graph of size vs time would be informative.  Here's the XKCD version: https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2240:_Timeline_of_the_Universe

Comment: @G.Smith I am thinking if it inflated quickly, it closely approached an asymptotic size in a short space of time.

Comment: In early theories of inflation, the observable part we can see was about the size of a grapefruit when inflation ended. Also, exponential growth doesn’t approach any asymptote.

Comment: @jamesqf Looking for a little more than a cartoon. I have added requests for numbers and calculations to my question.

Comment: @G.Smith Are these theories still held to? If the expansion is exponential, and hasn't approached an asymptote, then why has the universe not more than doubled in size in, say, the last second if it grew by much more than that in the first second?

Comment: As you correctly said in your first sentence, the inflationary (i.e., exponential) phase of expansion lasted only a tiny fraction of a second. Ever since, the expansion has been much slower, going first like $t^{1/2}$ and then like $t^{2/3}$, which are not even as fast as linear growth.

Answer (score 1):

No. The linear expansion since the universe was one day old is greater than a factor of 10 million. Bear in mind, however, that the earliest we can see is the CMB, about a hundred thousand years after the big bang, with a further expansion factor of a thousand since then. The inflationary epoch is itself simply a hypothesis to explain an apparent paradox. It is not observed, and nor is it predicted in general relativity, since significant "new physics" would be required to generate such a significant modification to the Friedmann cosmologies.

Comment: The new physics required (at least in the original inflationary models) is nothing more than another scalar field similar to the Higgs. The Friedmann equations don't get modified. Only the relation between energy density and pressure changes, and it changes in the way that scalar field theory says it must.

Comment: I've removed some comments debating whether inflation is "mainstream physics," as our community uses the term. Participants are invited to have that discussion on [meta] if they like.

Comment: @Charles FrancisHow did you calculate that? I am really looking for equations and numbers along with anything else that helps me understand this.

Comment: @David, for calculations I generally use http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/ACC.html. For understanding the concepts, I would suggest my first and second books. Equations are in the third. See my profile for links.